# UIViewController show ambiguous with any subviews inside it

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, ambiguous

I'm got a problem with a view controller which is holding some subviews. My view controller always shows position ambiguous if I added any other views so it makes my view controller cannot show full screen. I'm using View Debugging of XCode to know that warning error. But if the view controller blank, it's work like the bug never happened. This is so weird and I never see it for 4 years working with iOS. Did anyone know about this issue before and how to fix it?

when I add just one view inside:

[image]

And result:

[image]

And when I just set background for this viewcontroller

[image]

Comment: can you share demo project ?

Comment: Sadly I can't because it's my project at the company